# While implementing django-defender, Error (if response.get("X-Frame-Options") is not None: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get')

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-forms

Implementing a django-defender in web application causing an error while adding a syntax @watch_login in views.py

/views.py

```
    from defender.decorators import watch_login
    ...
    
    @watch_login # error caused due to...
    def login_user(request):
    ...
    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

Error-

```
Internal Server Error: /login
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 136, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py", line 27, in process_response
    if response.get("X-Frame-Options") is not None:
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get'
[28/Jun/2023 11:40:18] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 500 62726
```

Any solution for it...
ThankYou